# How to insert a list of objects into DB with dapper

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, dapper

I am making a website based on a Sql Server DB which is still in using by another application. The website is using a MySQL DB since is a SSH website. So I created a a new MySQL database for it and migrated all the data from Sql Server  to MySQL . 
Since the Sql Server  DB is still in use, it is updating everyday. I can't do the migration job everyday. So I am gonna make a program that read in tables (only 3 tables in the DB is used for the website.But each table has more than 3000 records) from Sql Server  DB and insert those tables into MySQL database. I am using Dapper for the program. I can read out the tables as lists e.g. List. Just wondering is there a good way to insert these lists into MySQL DB. I am using a for loop to insert the lists into DB now. Is there a better way? Thaks.

Comment: Please show your loop. If all properties have the same name as the database column you could simply pass the list as argument, f.e.: `int numInserted = connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[tdefErrorCode] ([idErrorCode],[ErrorCodeName]) VALUES (@idErrorCode, @ErrorCodeName);", ecList);`.

Comment: I am current using for() loop to loop through every row in the list. And insert the list into DB row by row.  The two DBs has exactly same tables and table columns. I'll try the method you provided. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works! Thanks. But the encoding looks not right in the MySQL database. Do you know how to change the encoding of the list? I've changed the MySQL database's encoding, not working. I created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510231/c-sharp-change-encoding-of-a-list-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

you can add object into your list by this.

```
List< table> tbl= new List< table>();
foreach (table tblname in collection)
{   

  table tblNew= new table { 
                  field1 = tblname .field1, 
                  field2 = tblname.field2  
                };
  tbl.Add(imgSIgn); 
}      

int res= cn.Execute(@"Insert INTO table(field1,field2) VALUES (@field1,@field2)", tbl.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

To Get data from the database

```
    String connectionString = "connectionstringtext";

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
    connection.open(); 
    List<ObjectTitle> objects = connection.Query<ObjectTitle>("SQL CODE").ToList();
    gloablListOfObjects = objects;
   }
}
```

To send data to the database

```
string conenctionString = "connectionstringtext"

using (var connection = new SQLConnection(connectionString)){
    connection.Open(); 
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Table (ID, Name, Address) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Address)";
    connection.Execute(sql, objectToAdd);
       }
}
```